# "Orlando" book sentence

Tags: grammar

Virginia Woolf said through a character that

> Once one looks at nature outside, one drops the pen, takes one's cloak, strides out of the room, and catches one's foot on a painted chest as one does so.

What does catches one's foot on painted chest mean.is chest a kind of box kept in open.TIA

Comment: It's not an "idiom", so I think we can only interpret it literally. The fact that the chest (a big piece of storage furniture, perhaps with drawers) happens to be "painted" is just an irrelevant detail. Even the fact that Orlando nearly tripped when walking past the chest doesn't really "mean" anything (but it is pointed out that he's *clumsy*). But I must say that as a *learner*, you really are making a rod for your own back by tackling texts like this.

Comment: But what an elegant rod!

Comment: Should I tackle or it not? I am not a tyro but  not a pro either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no idiomatic meaning here.  A chest is a type of large box, often made of wood, used for storing household items in. A "painted chest" is a chest that has been coloured with paint.

"Catching one's foot" means tripping over something. Your foot is "caught" by the chest, and you may fall or hurt yourself.

It doesn't mean anything special, but what the purpose of this sentence in the context of the story is more complex. Woolf is "painting a picture with words". She is trying to get into the inner life of her character. Understanding *Orlando* is difficult, not because the words are difficult (though some are), but because Woolf's characters are complex.